# toolbar background doesn't adjust and title is not shown - android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm trying to create a toolbar that uses a background I made in a png file.
Now, when I use the background in the xml, the layout editor in the android studio shows exactly the expected result. The problem comes when I run the app in the virtual device. The background doesn't adjust to the toolbar and as a result only a part of it gets shown.

Moreover, the title and the items are acting strange. The title is not shown at all and the only item that is displayed in the toolbar suddenly jumps to the left.

XML Code of the Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_styled"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:elevation="15dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_styled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Styled">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/action_bar_background"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

XML Code for the style of the toolbar:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Styled" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ToolBarTitleStyle</item>
    </style>
<style name="ToolBarTitleStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    </style>
```

And this is the MainActivity code which concerns the toolbar:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_styled);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Here is the images of the layout editor preview and the virtual device:

Layout Editor : https://i.gyazo.com/2b01f5ef9c87ecb35a605aa150aa6ad5.png

Virtual Device: https://i.gyazo.com/5bbd9bf5a2df1727278ba9e78efd622b.png

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in a AppBarLayout?

Comment: You fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest it like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cor_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_styled"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Styled">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/action_bar_background"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

then set them up like this:

```
   toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    collapse=(CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapseToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    collapse.setTitle("Title");
    collapse.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    collapse.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    collapse.setStatusBarScrimColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1) create one tool_bar.xml file in your res folder and paste the following code.
2) Include this tool_bar.xml file when ever you required.
3) Instantiate tool_bar object in .java file and do further process.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/action_bar_background"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<include id="@+id/tool_bar"
         layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```